# The past form of "must"

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I am quite puzzled over this usage of the word "must":

> "Members of his team said that he **must** forget everything he knew about swimming"

(This sentence is taken from English grammar textbook "Perspectives":

[image]

[image]

I was told that it was okay to say that, but this [Wikipedia table on modal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_auxiliary_verbs) says that the modal verb "must" doesn't have its past-tense form (unlike such modal verbs like, for example, "will" and "can" that have their clear past-tense forms "would" and "could"):

[image]

If so, then, as far as I understand, such past-tense sentense like "*They told him 10 years ago that he must forget everything*" must be grammatically incorrect (unlike some present-tense sentence like *"Today I am telling you that you must forget it!"*).

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Both okay. *Had to* may be the past, but a requirement for the future.

Comment: Neither is better. They mean different things.

Comment: @Lambie - Can you, please, elaborate?

Comment: "Must" does not have a preterite (past) form.

Comment: @BillJ - So, do you mean to say that the first sentence is grammatically incorrect? If yea, then how should I express the "must" meaning in the past?

Comment: No, it's fine. I was just commenting on the title of your question "The Past Form of Must",

Comment: @BillJ - Then I am confused: on one hand, you are saying that there is no past-tense  for "must", but on the other hand, you are saying that the sentence, in which "must" is used in the past-tense sense, is correct!

Comment: I have already explained that "must" does not have a preterite form. The time it relates to depends on the tensed verb in the clause that contains it.

Comment: @BillJ - So, it's like in case with "cut", "cost", "hit" and "set" - the past-tense form doesn't exist, but you can still use the base form in the past-tense context, right?

Comment: They have past tense forms that happen to have the same shape as their plain (infinitive) forms. In, for example, "He cut it with a knife", "cut" is the preterite (past) form of the verb "cut". But in "He wanted to cut it with a knife", "cut" is the plain (infinitive) form", not the preterite (past) form.

Comment: _"They have past tense forms that happen to have the same shape as their plain (infinitive) forms."_ - So, would it be correct to say that "must" also has its past-tense form that happens to have the same shape as the plain form? After all, in my example "must" is used in the past-tense sense.

Comment: No: "must" is present tense. It differs from most of the others in that it has no preterite (or plain) form.  If you want to learn more about English auxiliary verbs, I suggest you invest in a modern scholarly grammar textbook

Comment: _"No: "must" is present tense._ - I see. Well, in this case then saying something like "They said to him that he must forget that" (which is the first sentence in my question) is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I've already answered that point, and I don't intend to repeat it.

Comment: @BillJ - Well, you don't have to. However, I would be a liar if I said that I got your logic in your answers. Perhaps, someone else here will help me understand your logic.

Comment: @brilliant, This question is valid, but it's likely to be closed for two reasons: (1) it doesn't show any research on your part and doesn't tell us what aspect you're unsure of and what you already know, and (2) it's in the form of a request for proofreading. I'll be happy to answer it if you fix the question and ping me back in a comment.

Comment: @gotube - OK. I have edited my question. Please, check it out.

Comment: You must tell us the source of the quotation. Was it written by a non-native student or did you hear someone say that? Was it taken from a newspaper article, a magazine, a novel, "X" (Twitter), Facebook ? My guess it was written  by a non-native student because the time expression "ten years ago" would be better placed at the beginning of the sentence "***Ten years ago** his team members **said that he*** …”

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You are right. There was no "Ten yeas ago" in the original sentence. However, the context of the sentence, as denoted by the past-tense "said", as well as the whole story, was still the past tense. It took me a while to find the source. I just added it to the question.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't modify a perfectly valid sentence to prove a point, unless you explain what your purpose is. 2. Always cite your sources. 3. Editing the original sentence, and, quite drastically too, harms the answers that were posted earlier. 4 The original sentence is grammatical, it makes sense whereas your edited version lead me to believe the phrase was awkward and didn't seem authentic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The original sentence was NOT grammatical. It is already fully confirmed in the answer chosen as best given answer here. In short, using "must" in the past (relative to the moment of speaking) is ungrammatical because "must" doesn't have the past form. However, it is common in a spoken informal speech, hence my confusion. In my original question I intended just to give an example of this common usage (hence, no source was given). It could be anything: _"She said she must check it, but she never did", "Yesterday he said he must leave in 3 minutes. Why is he still here?"_ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically incorrect for the reasons you guess, and the Wikipedia chart confirms. If I were marking a standardized writing exam, I would mark this as an error.

The past perfect "*had learned*" makes it unambiguous that "must forget" has a past meaning, not a present one, so it's incorrect.

THAT SAID, in *unprepared speech*, rather than in writing, I could imagine a less educated native speaker saying this, and a lot of people not even noticing the mistake. I hear this type of mistake from sports broadcasters all the time.

So, it's not going to cause communication problems, but it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the correct way to express that thought then? Could I say something like "_They said that he was supposed to forget all he had learned_" instead? Or, perhaps "_he was to forget_" or "_he had to forget_" would fit the bill? BTW I just found the source and added it to my question. You can check it out if you want.

Comment: @brilliant The correct form without changing the meaning at all would be, "*Members of his team said that he **had to** forget everything he knew about swimming.*"

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Must is a *modal verb*. Modal verbs do not change in form to make different tenses. Both your examples are fine, but they are using different verbs. 'Must' and 'had to' are not irregular forms of the same verb.

Of course, as auxiliary verbs, modals are used alongside another verb which most likely will have different forms. So, for example, if you say "*you should **go***", retrospectively you might say "*you should have **gone***".

'Must' is used differently to 'should'. We use 'should' for actions or responsibilities that we think are best for the concerned subject. We use 'must' things that are considered *compulsory or *necessary*. For this reason, we don't use 'must' to say that someone ought to have done something in the past - we would usually just say that they *should have* done it to fulfil their compulsory obligation. When we do use 'must' about something in the past it is to express disbelief that it wasn't done.

Comment: What about "can" and "could", "will" and "would"?

Comment: @brilliant I'm not going to go through all of them, but the short answer is **no**. The modal verbs - can, could, may, might, must, ought to, shall, should, will and would - do not have different tenses. Take 'would' for example - you can use it to talk about something *hypothetical* in the future (eg "I would do that") or something hypothetical in the past (eg "I would have done that") but it isn't a different participle of the same verb because nothing has actually been *done*.

Comment: "Looking back, you can only say if they did or did not do it" - Not nessasserily only that. Looking back, I can also say what others told me in the past about what they considered then as something that would be imperative, appropriate, important, etc. for me to do in the future. In fact, my example in the question is exactly that case.

Comment: "I'm not going to go through all of them, but the short answer is no" - Sorry, but you are not saying the truth here. There are many grammar books teaching that "He said, "I will do it"" can be rewritten as "He said he would do it". Just like "He said, "I run this factory"" can be rewritten as "He said he ran that factory". In other words, just like "ran" is the past form of "run", "would" is the past form of "will".

Comment: @brilliant I don't see your example as different at all. To say you "*must forget*" doesn't have a corresponding past tense. The past tense of "forget" is "forgot", but if you did forget then the necessity is moot. You did it.

Comment: @brilliant In the example you just gave you introduced a whole other verb in the past tense - "*he **said***". You're quoting what someone said in the past, not what they *did*.

Comment: "I don't see your example as different at all" - You said, "Looking back, you can only say if they did or did not do it", but in my example they said neither of those two things because at the moment of speaking I hadn' started doing anything yet.

Comment: Some modals - _can_, _will_, and for some speakers _shall_ and _may_ - do retain their past _could_ _would_, _should_ and _might_ for some uses (particularly for backshifting in reported speech). But all those past forms have developed other uses and function as independent modals, without past tenses.

Comment: "In the example you just gave you introduced a whole other verb in the past tense - "he said" - LOL! That was just to provide the past-tense context. You should look at the word "will" and how it is changed in the past-tense context, instead. There can be many ways to provide the past-tense context, for example, "It was everyone's expectations that he would do that"

Comment: @ColinFine - "Some modals - can, will, and for some speakers shall and may - do retain their past could would, should and might for some uses (particularly for backshifting in reported speech)" - That's exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: "You're quoting what someone said in the past, not what they did" - Exactly! I am quoting what someone expected the other _would_ do. Definitely it is not about what others _did_, but about what others _would_ do. Nevertheless, the context is not present, but the past. Therefore, unlike what you said ("Looking back, you can only say if they did or did not do it"), one can also say, while looking back, something about what they or others _would_ do in the future (relative to the moment of speaking).

Comment: "These days we can swim" - Here the modal verb is "can". It expresses the ability to swim in the present. "In those days we could swim" - Here it has changed into "could" and therefore expresses the same ability, except in the past. Therefore, the modal verb "can" has the past form "could". These are, in fact, the basics of English that can be found in any English grammar book. Your answer is rather misleading.

Comment: @brilliant I really don't know what you're arguing about - modal verbs don't change form, that much is a fact. I will never understand why some people ask questions and then argue with a native English speaker over their answer - I can only assume that you're trying to prove someone else wrong and you're already resigned to the answer you want to hear.

Comment: @Astralbee: except for the ones that do, as I pointed out above.

Comment: @ColinFine I disagree. Those are alternative modals used when speaking in the past tense, not different forms of the same verb. They do not denote a change of tense otherwise the verb they 'help' wouldn't need to change. Take any other kind of auxiliary verb - "*I **am** running*" and "*I **was** running*", for example - the main verb doesn't change. But with a modal, such as in "*I should do it*" and "*I should have done it*", the modal doesn't change; the main verb does. If you can link me to a credible source that says "would" is a another form of "will", I'd love to see it.

Comment: "_But with a modal, such as in "I should do it" and "I should have done it", the modal doesn't change; the main verb does_" - You have completely ignored my example: "I can swim now" - "I could swim 10 years ago". Here the modal is changing. "_If you can link me to a credible source that says "would" is a another form of "will", I'd love to see it_" -  Check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_auxiliary_verbs The very first line of the table says that "will" is Plain Present and "would" is Preterite form of "would". Same with "can" and "could".

Comment: "_I will never understand why some people ask questions and then argue with a native English speaker over their answer_" - It's not as much me arguing with you as other native speakers who told me quite the opposite to what you are saying. BTW, being a native speaker doesn't automatically mean that your answers will always be correct.

Comment: @brilliant Okay this is absolutely my last word on this three-ring circus. Tense communicates an event's location in time. That's not my definition, that's lifted straight from a textbook. "I am swimming" and "I swam" could both refer to the same event. You say one in the present, and one about the past. "I **can** swim" refers, not to an event, but to your *ability* to swim. If you then said "I **could** swim", that neither refers to an event that is now in the past nor does it mean the same thing - in fact, it can mean the opposite, because "I could swim" sounds like you no longer can.

Comment: @Astralbee - (1) _"I could swim" sounds like you no longer can_ - This point is quite irrelevant. Depending on the context, the phrase "In those days I swam" can also mean that now, in these days, the speaker is no longer swimming. _"Tense communicates an event's location in time.That's not my definition, that's lifted straight from a textbook."_- Can you provide a link to that textbook where it states that tenses communicate only the location of events and not of anything else like ability, existence, etc.?

Comment: @Astralbee - (2) I wouldn't say that "There is a planet" and "There was a planet" communicate anything about any kind of event. Rather, those two sentences communicate to us something about the existence of something (that is, the existence of a planet).

Comment: @Astralbee - (3) _""I can swim" refers, not to an event, but to your ability to swim"_ - Yes, it does. And the sentence like "I can swim these days" communicates the location of that ability in the present, while a sentence like "When I was ten, I already could swim" communicates the location of that ability in the past. And the form of the modal verb here therefore changes from "can" to "could". Everything is logical and falls into category of communicating the location of something in time. BTW, did you check the link I gave you? Or did you just decide to ignore it?

Comment: @brilliant "location of ability"? My goodness.

Comment: @Astralbee - Yes, location of ability in time, that is, whether one refers to some ability in the present time ("like in "I can swim now") or in the past (like in "I could swim 10 years ago"). Just like earlier you were saying about the location of an event in time (_"Tense communicates an event's location in time"_) So, I, in fact, am using your terminology here. Did you check the link where it says that "would" is the past-tense from of "will"?

Comment: @brilliant I'd love to chat more but I must have had to go.

Comment: @Astralbee - :) That's understood.

Answer (score 0):

The passage speaks about Lewis Pugh, a swimmer, an idealist and a fervent environmentalist who swims the icy waters of lake Imja, 5,300 metres above sea level.

He failed the first time because he was swimming fast, therefore his crew urged him to change tactics and *say* at this altitude he *must forget* [present] everything *he knew about swimming* [past]; instead of swimming fast *he must swim* [present] as slowly as possible.

The original text uses “said" but if the author had written *say* it would have been easier to see why the modal verb *must* was kept and not substituted with *had to*. With *had to* the reader would have lost the sense of urgency, immediacy and drama in the team members' voice that the historical present has.

The **[historical present](https://www.thoughtco.com/historical-present-verb-tense-1690928)** is used to narrate past events, it brings the action  *alive*, it also adds drama to a story, which is why some call it the *dramatic present*. The **deontic must** employed in the original text is often uttered by authoritative figures such as parents, employers, coaches, and doctors but in this scenario the crew is not *commanding* Pugh to swim slowly; they are *urging* him to go against his instincts and everything he knows about swimming in perilous situations (swimming in the North Pole is given as an example). In this instance, *must* denotes **deontic *necessity***.

In her blog, *All Things Linguistics*, the linguist [Gretchen McCulloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gretchen_McCulloch) explains

> Notice that English is generally good at making distinctions between necessity and possibility but **bad at making distinctions between epistemic and deontic, which must be cleared up via context**. Some languages do make straightforward lexical distinctions between various flavours of modality like epistemic and deontic.

She provides an easy-to-use [diagram](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/138048860136/the-difference-between-epistemic-deontic) which illustrates the two different modalities

[image: epistemic vs deontic diagram]

> In the diagram, the blue areas are epistemic modality (according to evidence, reasoning, or beliefs), the red areas are deontic modality (according to a set of rules or desires), **the dark areas are necessity (in all possible worlds)**, the light areas are possibility (in at least one possible world).

> **Dark blue** is epistemic necessity
> “It must be raining outside (I can hear the rain).” In all worlds consistent with my beliefs, it is raining outside.

> **Dark red** is deontic necessity
> “It **must** rain this week (in order for the crops not to spoil)” In all worlds consistent with my desires, it rains this week.

Comment: _"The original text uses “said" but if the author had written "say" it would have been..."_ - If the author had written "say" this whole question would have never been posted because the historical present in the passage would have been absolutely clear to me, in which case "must" would have been absolutely grammatical.

Comment: @brilliant so you agree (in part) with my analysis, this makes me happy.  But  I also said “… *it would have been easier to see **why** "must“ was kept*", *say* might have been preferable (at least to me) but it's not wrong to use "said" in that context, the author of the piece is switching tenses to enhance the drama of the situation. Lastly, before we get into an argument of which I have no time to enter, this the only post which uses reliable and credible resources to support  their answer.

Comment: gotube's post also uses reliable and credible resource - the only reason why he didn't provide the link to the Wikipedia chart on modals is because I had already added that link to my original question. Your point on justifying "said" in the passage (as opposed to "say") still needs a resource confirming that switching to the historical past right in the middle of a sentence, especially right after "said", is acceptable.

Comment: @brilliant  My answer says and explains quite clearly that the tense in "must forget everything" is present and why it is used appropriately in this case. I don't see any answer that mentions **deontic** or **epistemic must**. I also supplied a reliable and authoritative source for "deontic necessity" but that doesn't satisfy you either. This is my last comment on the matter. Thank you in any case for editing the question and providing the original source and also for changing your edited version with the original. Once I read that everything began to click into place.

Answer (score -2):

It is perfectly reasonable and common for a sentence to mix verb tenses, if the actions in the sentence happen at different times.

A trivial example would be, "Yesterday I read a book and tomorrow I will watch a movie." The reading happened yesterday and so is past tense. The watching won't happen until tomorrow and so is future tense.

A slightly more complex example: "Yesterday I decided that I will go on vacation next Thursday." The deciding happened yesterday and so is past tense. But the trip itself is not until next Thursday and so is future tense.

"Must" doesn't make sense in past tense. "Must" makes a statement into a command, "You must do this". You can't command someone to do something in the past (assuming he doesn't have a time machine). You can only command someone to do something in the future.

So, "Members of his team said to him ten years ago that he must forget everything he had learned in school" makes perfect sense. The saying happened ten years ago and so is past tense. But what they said was a command of something he must do in the then-future. They didn't tell him that he must forget these things the day before they told him to forget. That would be logically impossible. They said he must forget sometime after they instructed him.

Consider, "Members ... said to him ten years ago that he will forget ..." The saying is ten years ago. The forgetting is in the future.

Side note: The future from when they said it, not necessarily from today. Like if I said, "In 1942 Winston Churchill said, 'We will win this war'", the saying is in the past. The winning is in the future from when he said it. By now that is also past, but it was future when he said it, so he used the future tense.

Comment: (1) "_A trivial example would be, "Yesterday I read a book and tomorrow I will watch a movie."_"
- I don't quite see how this one is a good example of "mixing verb tenses". The verb "read" here denotes an action that took place in the past (relative to the time of speaking) as denoted by the word "yesterday". Hence we have the past-tense form "read". And the the action of watching a movie belongs to the future (relative to the time of speaking) as denoted by the word "tomorrow". Hence we have "will".

Comment: (2) We don't see in this sentence the word "will" describing an action of the past, nor do we see the past-tense "read" describing a future action. Same with _"Yesterday I decided that I will go on vacation next Thursday."_ The past-form "decided" describes an action of the past (that is, of yesterday) and the word "will" describes the action of going on vacation, which is, relative to the moment of speaking, of the future. So, where is that "mixing of verb tenses" in these two examples?

Comment: (3) "Consider, "Members ... said to him ten years ago that he will forget ..." The saying is ten years ago. The forgetting is in the future" - If by the moment of saying this sentence this future has already become the past, that is, the act of forgetting has already transpired, then this sentence is grammatically incorrect. The correct way would be this: _"Members ... said to him ten years ago that he WOULD forget ..."_.

Comment: (4) However, if even now, that is, 10 years later, he has still not forgotten, then the sentence _"Members ... said to him ten years ago that he WILL forget ..."_ is still correct because the word "will" in it refers to the time, which is still the future relative to the moment of saying this sentence.

Comment: @brilliant RE "trivial example": That's the point. One action is in the past and so uses past tense; another action is in the future and so uses future tense. So both past and future are used in the same sentence.

Comment: I'm not saying that a future tense is used to refer to a past action or vice versa. I'm saying that one sentence can include multiple tenses. If one action referred to in the sentence is in the past and another action referred to in the same sentence is in the future, then we use different tenses to relate them.

Comment: (1) "I'm saying that one sentence can include multiple tenses."
- That's correct, but that doesn't mean that you can always lump together different tenses in one sentence whatever way you want, especially when one verb is employed to describe the contents of someone's talk, for example, when a verb follows the verb "said".

Comment: (2) You CAN'T use plain present form of a verb to denote something that is the future from the point of view of someone's talk in the sentence, yet is already the past from the point of view of the time when the whole sentence is produced. Take a look: _"She said she WILL come, so we're still waiting for her"_ - correct. _"She said she WOULD come, so we're still waiting for her"_ - correct. _"She said she WOULD come, but she never did"_ - correct. _"She said she WILL come, but she never did"_ - wrong!

Comment: "That doesn't mean that you can always lump together different tenses in one sentence whatever way you want ..." Of course not. Each verb should have the correct tense for the action described. You appear to be interpreting my words to mean that you can use whatever tense you feel like for any verb regardless of when it happens. If I was unclear and gave that impression, sorry. No, the tense of each verb must match when the action that that verb describes takes place.

Comment: @brilliant "She said she will come." At some time in the past, she said that, in the future, from the point of view of the time when she made the statement, she will come. That sentence is completely valid. Why do you say it's wrong?

Comment: "That sentence is completely valid. Why do you say it's wrong?" - Because that's future-in-the-past, in which case "will" must be turned into "would": _"She says now that she will do it, so I hope she will."_ -> _"She said 20 years ago that she would do that, and yet she never did."_ The "future" in the second sentence is already in the past relative to the time of speaking. In other words, the time when she had a chance to deliver on her promise is already over.